# Share java files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I am using Eclipse to develop a Java program. If I want to share the code (Java files) with someone else (who is also using Eclipse), what would be the easiest way? We do not have a source repository set up yet.

Comment: if by "not yet" you mean you will have a source repository later, why not just set it up now?

Comment: We do not have a source repository set up *yet* ... isn't that like step 1 when you create a new project. My vote goes to setting up your version control system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send them the example.java files via email or Skype and they could add them to their project if you wanted to go old school. 
I think a repository like Github or Subversion will be your best bet.

I vote for setting up a repository :)

Comment: +1 - Github is exactly what you want for sharing your repository with others.

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly** suggest to consider setting up a source repository for your usage. Meanwhile, you can try something like this:

`Export` your project files: (After selecting your project), `File` > `Export` > `General` > `Archive File`

The `import` option works almost in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is a free subversion tool you and your friend can download.

http://tortoisesvn.net/

It would be most beneficial if you went ahead and set up your repository now, rather than later, especially since you are both interested in starting development.